# Requesting 400 links with multithreading and ThreadPool

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, console

I am working on multi-threading application to learn multithreading better.
My application has a queue with 400 unique links, 4 threads and each thread is pulling link from the queue and sending a Get request to this queue.

My application seems to run, and it takes 18 - 22 seconds for it to finish on 400 links.
I am using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to do the multithreading.

I wanted someone to review my code and tell me if I use `ThreadPool` in the correct way.
I need it to be efficient as it can be.

I created a similar application in Python and it takes 12 seconds to run 400 requests.  Therefore, I think I am not using the multithreading ability of C# correctly.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlayGround
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            RunThreadPool();
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Elapsed time: {0}", elapsedMs / 1000);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static BlockingCollection<string> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529659/wait-for-queueuserworkitem-to-complete
        private static ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        private static void RunThreadPool()
        {
            string url = @"https://google.com";
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var tempWorkerId = i;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Worker(tempWorkerId));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", url + "/" + i);
                inputQueue.Add(url + "/" + i);
                //Thread.Sleep(50);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
            inputQueue.CompleteAdding();

            resetEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/22689821/2153777
        static void Worker(int workerId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

            foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                string res = "";
                //Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, workItem);
                try
                {
                    res = Get(workItem);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    res = "404";
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1} with result {2}", workerId, workItem, res);
                //Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
            }
            resetEvent.Set();
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108442/2153777
        public static string Get(string uri)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                status = response.StatusCode;
            }

            //Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return status.ToString() + "; Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Using `async\await` was very slow (44 seconds) (4.12.2018)**
Following the comments about using `async\await`, I used the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall#example) from Microsoft to create a version with `async\await` and it seems to work faster than anything else I tried.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncAwait
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SumPageSizesAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task SumPageSizesAsync()
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            // Make a list of web addresses.  
            List<string> urlList = SetUpURLList();

            // Create a query.   
            IEnumerable<Task<HttpStatusCode>> downloadTasksQuery =
                from url in urlList select GetURLStatusCodeAsync(url);

            // Use ToArray to execute the query and start the download tasks.  
            Task<HttpStatusCode>[] downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();

            // You can do other work here before awaiting.  

            // Await the completion of all the running tasks.  
            HttpStatusCode[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Elapsed time: {0}", elapsedMs / 1000);
        }

        private static async Task<HttpStatusCode> GetURLStatusCodeAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status;

            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

                // Send the request to the Internet resource and wait for  
                // the response.  
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
                {
                    status = response.StatusCode;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("[*] Status code: {0}, Thread: {1}, Url: {2}", status, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, url);

            return status;
        }

        private static List<string> SetUpURLList()
        {
            string url = @"https://google.com";
            List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
            {
                urls.Add(url + "/" + i);
            }

            return urls;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the same with `async/await` or do just want to use threads?

Comment: I didn't try it. I don't care too much. I am trying to find the fastest and correct way to use multithreading. You think it should improve the performance?

Comment: async-await example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall

Comment: @t3chb0t @Nkosi, I used `async\await` (see my last edit from 4.12.2018) and it took between 36 - 44 seconds. Very slow compared to my first method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your use of `ManualResetEvent` is incorrect in this scenario, because as I read it, you intend to wait for all threads to complete here:

> ```
>         resetEvent.WaitOne();
>         Console.WriteLine("Done.");
> ```

But you actually only wait for the first thread to call `resetEvent.Set()`.

Instead you'll have to provide a `ManualResetEvent` (or another waithandle type - for instance `ManualResetEventSlim`) for each thread in order to wait for them all to end. This could be done like this:

```
private static void RunThreadPool()
{
  string url = @"https://google.com";
  List<ManualResetEvent> waitHandles = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    waitHandles.Add(waitHandle);
    int workerId = i;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Worker(workerId, waitHandle));
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Starting adding.");
  for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
  {
    inputQueue.Add(url); // + "/" + i);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
  inputQueue.CompleteAdding();

  WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());

  waitHandles.ForEach(wh => wh.Dispose());
  //resetEvent.WaitOne();
  Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}

static void Worker(int workerId, ManualResetEvent waitHandle)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

  foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
  {
    string res = "";
    try
    {
      res = Get(workItem);
      Console.WriteLine($"{res} - {workerId}");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      res = "404";
    }
  }
  waitHandle.Set();
  Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
}
```

Besides that I think your use of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` is OK.

---

It is not quite clear what kind of concurrency you are exercising but if it's just about executing an action on each element in an existing collection in a multi threaded/parallel manner then, you can experiment with `Parallel.ForEach(..)`:

```
private static void RunParallel()
{
  string url = @"https://google.com";

  List<string> inputQueue = new List<string>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
  {
    inputQueue.Add(url); // + "/" + i);
  }

  int workerId = 0;
  ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
  options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;
  Parallel.ForEach(inputQueue, options, (uri) =>
  {
    Worker(workerId++, uri);
  });

  Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}

static void Worker(int workerId, string uri)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

  string res = "";
  try
  {
    res = Get(uri);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    res = "404";
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
}
```

If you experiment with different values of `options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` you can investigate how the `Parallel` react to that in the use of threads and how it may influence on performance.

Comment: I'd use [semaphore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore) instead (workers call Release, main calls WaitOne four times). +1 Anyway

Comment: @Henrik Hansen, thanks. The last method with the `Parallel.ForEach(..)` was the fastet (14 seconds).  Btw, I also tried `async\await` (my last edit from 4.12.2018) but it was much slower compared to your suggestions.